# Is it possible to automate NetTerm application using UFT?

Tags: hp-uft

Is it possible to automate NetTerm Application using UFT12.2? I tried configuring the TE Add-in in UFT, but no luck.

Looking for an expert advice on how to go about this.

NETTERM SOURCE - http://www.securenetterm.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Netterm Source support HLLAPI ?

If not, UFT can automate Terminal applications using Text Recognition.

You need to go to Tools -> Options -> GUI Testing -> Terminal Emulator and select Open Wizzard.

Then over there do the necessary configurations to enable Text Recognition and not HLLAPI integration.